Type error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Product'
I am using NextJs, Typescript, Prisma and MongoDb. Everything works fine when i run "npm run build". But when I am trying to deploy a project on Vercel, I am getting this error:
Type error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Product'.
Here is my prisma.schema:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"  
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Product {
  id               String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  category         String
  imageSRC         String
  name             String
  onStock          Int
  price            Int
  quantityPerUnit  String
  type             String
  shortDescription String
  longDescription  String
  createdAt        DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime    @updatedAt
  CartItem         CartItem[]
  orderItems       OrderItem[]

  @@map("products")
}

And here is a part of my code, where i have an error:
import {  Product } from '@prisma/client'

interface ProductCardProps {
  product: Product;
}


export default function ProductCard({product} : ProductCardProps) {
  const productPrice = (product.price).toLocaleString("ru-RU") + " сум";
  return (


Tried to add this on prisma.schema

output = "../../node_modules/.prisma/client"


you are not exporting Product model, export Product model or use like this const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client"); const prisma = new PrismaClient(); then access like this prisma.Product

if you want to use tables you should npx prisma generate on the terminal
it command gives you hints for table columns

What do you mean? In project i have already  used this command and generated prisma schema. Should I add this command during the deployment?

Add the following to your package.json scripts
"postinstall": "prisma generate"

You need to tell vercel to generate the types within your schema. In this case, the Product table does not exist as a type until you run prisma generate. You don't encounter this error locally, because presumably you ran prisma generate on your computer before you ran npm run build, and npm run build was able to find the Product type.

You can see solution on Vercel Docs about PRISMA
Add
{
  ...
  "scripts" {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  }
  ...
}

If you see prisma: command not found errors during your deployment to Vercel,
you are missing prisma in your dependencies.
By default, prisma is a dev dependency and may need to be moved to be a standard dependency.

